# Regular expresion with exceptions

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I want to know if there is a pattern in a vector, lets say:

```
vector <- c(paste0(paste("MC", 1:25), c(rep("", 10), rep("-P1",10), rep("P1",5))), rep("RANDOM", 10),c("MC1","MC2","MC-3"), rep("MCRANDOM", 10))
vector
```

I want the ones with "MC"  and are followed by a number. Between these can be the number, or a hyphen or a space and then the number. I want to exclude those that are part of a larger code, the ones with P and another number, like these: "MC 20-P1" "MC 21P1".
This detects the ones with MC and number:

```
vector[grepl("MC( |-)*[0-9]{1,}", vector)]
```

I tried to use  a `^`for exclution, but my attempt failed:

```
vector[grepl("MC( |-)*[0-9]{1,}[^(-*)P]", vector)]
```

How can i to match just the ones with MC and numbers? (in my real data are part of a larger text)

Comment: Do u ned `grep("^MC[- ]\\d+", vector, value = TRUE)`

Comment: No, i Need just: `"MC 1"     "MC 2"     "MC 3"     "MC 4"     "MC 5"     "MC 6"     "MC 7"     "MC 8"     "MC 9"     "MC 10"`

Comment: ` Between these can be the number, or a hyphen or a space and then the number.` so `MC-3` not wanted? `grep("^MC[- ]\\d+$", vector, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Oh, i forgot that, Yes I whant those too

Comment: There are not in my examble, but there arelike: "MC-1"     "MC-2". I want to exclude those like "MC 16-P1" and "MC 24P1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the start (`^`) and end (`$`) here to match the strings that starts with 'MC' followed by space or `-` and then one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end

```
grep("^MC[- ]?\\d+$", vector, value = TRUE)
#[1] "MC 1"  "MC 2"  "MC 3"  "MC 4"  "MC 5"  "MC 6"  
#[7] "MC 7"  "MC 8"  "MC 9"  "MC 10" "MC1"   "MC2"   "MC-3"
```

If the `MC` can be a substring, then use word boundary (`\\b`) in place of `^`

Comment: that almost do the job, but, aI also want those like: "MC2"      "MC3"